# Why is the PHP crypt() function returning the same thing for two different strings?

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection

I'm using PHP's `crypt` function for password hashing/encryption, but I don't think I am doing it right because "nathan12" and "nathan123" both allow me to login to my account on my system (the actual password is "nathan123", and therefore "nathan12" or anything else should **NOT** allow me to login).

Here's what my system does when a user registers:

```
[...]

$salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
$password = crypt($password, $salt); // '$password' is the inputted password

$insertUserStmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, 
username, 
password, 
password_salt, 
email, 
created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$insertUserStmt->bind_param("sssssi", $name, $username, $password, $salt, $email, time());

$insertUserStmt->execute();

[...]
```

It inserts the hashed/encrypted password (`$password`) into the database along with the `$salt`.

When someone tries to login, the following is done to check if the user has inputted the correct password for the username they inputted:

```
[...]

// $password_salt is from DB; $password is inputted password
$password_crypt = crypt($password, $password_salt); 

// $login_password is from DB
if($password_crypt == $login_password) { 

[...]
```

I'm probably not even using the `crypt` function properly, but according to the PHP docs the first parameter is a string (the password) and second is the salt.

Comment: Have you checked to see if different hashes are being stored in the database? Without more information it's hard to pin down the problem. (Also note: if you're using PHP 5.5+, you should really be using [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for this.)

Comment: @Amber Yes, I checked in my database and the hash is different for all users (there are only two users at the moment - me and a test account). But I don't think that would make a difference for one user since the password is the same and it shouldn't allow me to type in two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The standard DES-based `crypt()` [...] only uses the first eight characters of `str`, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Use a salt that starts with `$<algo>$` to use something other than DES. See the `crypt()` documentation for details.

Comment: I tried prepending `$<algo>$` to the salt and then appending the password key from [Sam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20876026/507629) (below) to the salt and it works for "nathan123" but for just "nathan" it returns "$" and for "nathan12" it returns the same thing as "nathan123" so `crypt` doesn't seem very reliable at all. `crypt($password, "$<algo>$" . $password_salt . PASSWORD_KEY)` The constant `PASSWORD_KEY` is the key from Sam's answer.

Comment: @Nathan: Which algorithm did you select?

Comment: Okay, I prepended `$5$` to the salt (which is the `sha-256` algorithm)   and it looks like it is working now. I tried "nathan", "nathan1", etc. and it generated a different encryption for all of them. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead of crypt, for the reasons you mention: "I'm probably not even using the crypt function properly". You  say you are getting the salt from the DB... this sounds insecure.  with password_hash() you can let PHP handle the salting for you in a secure manner.

More details on why this is superior:
http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/

Comment: Getting the salt from the DB isn't inherently insecure. That's what `password_hash` would be doing as well; it just happens to store the salt in the same string as the password, rather than in a separate field.

Comment: @Amber correct. Not inherently insecure, but as he mentioned he's not quite sure what he's doing, I have a feeling he could very well be storing a single salt and using it for all users.

Comment: @DigitalChris In my setup each user has their own salt (I have even checked in my DB). But I will use password_hash instead and try what the other answerers have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You should use more than just a password salt to encrypt passwords.

You can store a random string in your configuration file.

```
$config['passwordKey'] = 'asjdfa783#H$Khjsdfhas78a734J%JSDGK2348235hxmfdA';
```

And append it to `$salt` when encrypting. This way if the database is compromised, and your file system is not, then attackers can't decrypt your database password hashes. This should be essential to protect the users information on other sites with identical login information.

---

To hash your passwords, `password_hash` is a simple `crypt()` wrapper specially configured for password hashing!
([source](https://www.php.net/password_hash))

```
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(
    'cost' => 60,
    'salt' => $salt . $config['passwordKey']
));
```